# how to add images to mysql database when a user submit their images

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to add multiple images into mysql database using a form. Whenever a user submits that form then it captures all data and stores that into mysql database. (it is right way, but i need)

My database table is looking like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `Owner_detail` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fullname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `List1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `List2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `List3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ownermobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `image_one` blob NOT NULL,
  `image_two` blob NOT NULL,
  `image_three` blob NOT NULL,
  `otherdetail` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=49 ;
```

My html form is looking like this.

```
<table width="60%"><form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="tripleplay" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('fullname','','R','area','','R','ownermobile','','RisNum','email','','RisEmail','otherdetail','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">
  <tr>
    <td width="44%">Full Name : </td>
    <td width="56%"><input size="25" type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Rental Type:</td>


    <td>

    <select name='List1' id="List1"     onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
<option selected>Make a Selection</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select name='List2' id="List2" onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])">
  <option selected>Make a Selection</option>
</select><br /><br />
<select name='List3' id="List3" onchange="getValue(this.value,     this.form['List2'].value, 
this.form['List1'].value)">
      <option selected>Make a Selection</option>
    </select>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Area : </td>
    <td><input size="25" type="text" name="area" id="area" />
  sq.ft.</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Owner Mobile / Landline</td>
    <td><input size="25" type="text" name="ownermobile" id="ownermobile" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>E-mail</p></td>
    <td><input size="25" type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Pictures of Property</td>
     <td>

       <input type="file" name="image_one" id="image_one" />


        <input type="file" name="image_two" id="image_two" />


        <input type="file" name="image_three" id="image_three" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Other details you would like to share about your property:</td>
    <td><textarea size="25" name="otherdetail" id="otherdetail" cols="45" rows="5">    </textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

and my processing form in php is looking like this

```
<?
if( $_POST )
{
  $con =     mysql_connect("","","");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("vkrental", $con);

  $users_fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
  $users_area = $_POST['area'];
  $users_List1 = $_POST['List1'];
  $users_List2 = $_POST['List2'];
  $users_List3 = $_POST['List3'];
  $users_ownermobile = $_POST['ownermobile'];
  $users_email = $_POST['email'];
  $users_image_one = $_POST['image_one'];
  $users_image_two = $_POST['image_two'];
  $users_image_three = $_POST['image_three'];
  $users_otherdetail = $_POST['otherdetail'];


  $users_fullname = htmlspecialchars($users_fullname);
  $users_area = htmlspecialchars($users_area);
  $users_List1 = htmlspecialchars($users_List1);
  $users_List2 = htmlspecialchars($users_List2);
  $users_List3 = htmlspecialchars($users_List3);
  $users_ownermobile = htmlspecialchars($users_ownermobile);
  $users_email = htmlspecialchars($users_email);
  $users_image_one = htmlspecialchars($users_image_one);
  $users_image_two = htmlspecialchars($users_image_two);
  $users_image_three = htmlspecialchars($users_image_three);
  $users_otherdetail = htmlspecialchars($users_otherdetail);




  $query = "
  INSERT INTO `vkrental`.`Owner_detail` (

`fullname` ,
`area` ,
`List1` ,
`List2` ,
`List3` ,

`ownermobile` ,
`email` ,
`image_one` ,
`image_two` ,
`image_three` ,
`otherdetail`
)
VALUES ( '$users_fullname',
        '$users_area', '$users_List1','$users_List2','$users_List3',     '$users_ownermobile', '$users_email',     '$users_image_one','$users_image_two','$users_image_three', '$users_otherdetail'
        );";

  mysql_query($query);

  echo "<h2>Success.</h2>";

   mysql_close($con);
}
 ?>
```

My Problem is when ever I am inserting images from mysql database it stores successfully. 
but when i am doing that from my html form it is not storing images. it is storing only data(text).

I don't know what is the actual error in my forms.

Comment: This is not how file uploads work. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: My suggestion would be to upload the images in a particular folder and storing their `URL`s in the database (as `varchar`) and not directly as `blob` data type.

Comment: @Kevin adding some code and send reply how it is possible

Comment: htmlspecialchars() is not the correct way to escape data so it can be stored in a database. Also note that all `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what using `htmlspecialchars()` for binary data would do.

```
$users_image_one = htmlspecialchars($users_image_one);
$users_image_two = htmlspecialchars($users_image_two);
```

[Edit:]

`htmlspecialchars()` is used to preserve special characters of **text data**. However, if you use it for **binary data**, it would mess up everything.

### **Troubleshoot them yourself:**

You can try to find out the problem by first just uploading only the images.

Also have a look at this link : [File upload using POST method](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: There's plenty more stuff he needs to do than that. He's not dealing with the uploaded files at all

Comment: @user2481198 Sorry, my mistake. Edited my answer.

Comment: @KevinPaladin     $users_image_one = htmlspecialchars($users_image_one);
    $users_image_two = htmlspecialchars($users_image_two); if i doing same procedure with this code it is running. if i remove this code also it is running. but images are not in both ways.

Comment: @KevinPaladin i think the problem is form action="process.php" i am using but some others are says action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" then what i am suing now?

Comment: @user2481198 as suggested by Pekka , I would suggest you to have a look at this link first http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php :)

Answer (score -1):

Does not sound like there is an error . . . .

You don't store the actual images in your database, but rather just their name, or a reference to the images

e.g. product_one.jpg

Then when you want to display it you would do something like

```
<img src=" <?php $echo \images\$users_image_one ?> ">
```